# Access information from a different ViewController

Tags: xcode, google-maps, viewcontroller

I'm not sure how to ask this question, so I will try to explain what I am trying to accomplish to the best of my ability.

I have a view controller that is primarily google maps. then I have another view controller titled postController which allows the users to post some information to the map. I would like to access some of the user's information from the maps controller so that the post controller knows the user's location in order to store it to firebase. I was wondering if this is possible? I have checked around and I have found some questions or examples that are kind of similar but not really.

Comment: A bit more information would be useful; what is the relationship between the two controllers? i.e. is it a master->detail relationship where an action in one controller opens another or are they both child controllers of another controller? Perhaps some (brief) code showing how the controllers are instantiated would help.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for your response. The two controllers are not related at all. One controller is strictly maps and the post controller allows users to post some type of information to the map. I would like for the user's location which is on the map controller to be accessed in the post